# Terminology for relationships defined by interfaces

Tags: java, .net, oop, interface, terminology

If inheritance is the OO technique for implementing an **is-a** relationship and composition/aggregation implements a **has-a** relationship what would would the appropriate name for the relationship implemented by a Java/.NET style interface be?

I'm really keen on the term **can-do** relationship since such interfaces are often used to specify supported operations such as *Sortable*, *Clonable* etc. plus it sounds really affirmative. The only name that comes to mind that I've actually seen is a **realizes** relationship but it doesn't really describe all that much.

Answer (score 2):

In most Object Oriented Programing Languages, Interfaces and classes both impart their relationship through inheritance, and inheritance is an **is-a** relationship, regardless of whether it's an interface, class, abstract class, etc...

In fact, classes are themselves interfaces of a sort, they simply also provide an implementation as well.  There isn't a huge difference between an abstract class with no implementations and an interface, although the implementation internally may have some differences.  (the biggest being that in Java and .NET you can't inherit multiple abstract classes)

So from a conceptual oop perspective, is-a is inheritance.  has-a is containment/composition/aggregation/whateveryouwanttocallit,

The term "realizes" is more of a subclass of "inherits" or "subclasses".  You can't Subclass an interface, but you can realize it.  This is more of fine detail, although it is one that has specific meaning.

Not all languages have interfaces.  C++, for instance, doesn't.  However, you can fake them with abstract classes with no implementations as I mentioned earlier, but since C++ allows multiple inheritance the issue isn't as much of a problem (so long as they are pure abstract classes with no implementations, if you start mixing code into them then it gets hairier)

Comment: Concept of Interface is not tied to inheritance.

Comment: @Mik378 - True, some languages, such as smalltalk can implement an interface without inheritance.  They simply need to implement all the members that the interface implements and they "are-a" whatever.  99.9% of all oop languages implement interfaces through inheritance though, and likewise inheritance in every language I can think of is a form of an interface (otherwise, polymorphism wouldn't work).

Comment: @Mik378 - but then Smalltalk can do any kind of is-a relationship that way without inheritance.  one object is-a 'nother object if they both have the same signature.  C# can do the same thing with dynamic variables.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most significant term for you're searching for is: **Role**.

An interface describes a **Role**.

That's why a lot of interfaces has the suffix "able":
`Cloneable`, `Serializable`, `Runnable` etc.

It's like assigning one or several roles.

Comment: I wouldn't call that an oop term, although certain oop methodologies may use that terminology.  I tend to stick to the common terms that most of the methodologies agree on.

Comment: @Erik The OP is just about Java/.NET.

Comment: No, the question is about how a specific feature of C#/Java would be labeled in an object oriented terminology.

Comment: I didn't say anything about a language.  I said Methodology.  Methodologies define terms and nomenclature.

Answer (score 0):

**is-a** is reasonable for interfaces as well.  In Java an `ArrayList` **is-a** `List` and a `TreeMap` **is-a** `Map`.

If you write a method which accepts a `List` as an argument:

```
public void someMethod(List someList) {
    // ...
}
```

It is valid to pass an instance of `ArrayList` as an argument to that method because an `ArrayList` is a `List`.